# Difference of HUD behavior in between Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, unity, hud

It seems to me that when press Alt and type, in 14.04, it only searches the menu of the current program. However, in ubuntu 12.04 it searches the menus of the programs running in the background.

E.g., in 14.04, Alt then "Log out" it does nothing, however in 12.04 it will give the option of logout of the system.

My question is, is there a way we set 14.04 HUD work just like in 12.04?

Thanks a lot in advance!